# how to get a min and max value that is equal to a specific cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I tried a formula to equal the ranges to a cell value. But the output is not as I expected. I think this should be in a for each loop not in a formula.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the data:

```
Col:A     Col:B

1001       abc
1002       abc
1003       abc
1004       abc
1005       abc
1006       xyz
1007       xyz
1008       xyz
1009       xyz
1010       xyz
```

Here is the formula that I tried:

`"=CONCATENATE(MIN(IF(B2:B250=B2,A2:A250)),"-",MAX(IF(B2:B250=B2,A2:A250)))"`

and the output is:

```
Col: A         Col:B
1001-1010       abc
1002-1010       abc
1003-1010       abc
1004-1010       abc
1005-1010       abc
1006-1010       xyz
1007-1010       xyz
1008-1010       xyz
1009-1010       xyz
1010-1010       xyz
```

The output that i want to achieve is:

```
Col: A     Column b
1001-1005   abc
1006-1010   xyz
```

Comment: Hello, coder. do you want to solve the problem using Excel Formulars or a VBA Macro?

Comment: @G.M better if it is vba macro :)

Comment: I almost managed to do it with this array formula (data is in range A2:B11 and needs to be sorted on column B):
{=TEXTJOIN(" - ",TEXT(MIN(INDIRECT(CONCAT(ADDRESS(ROW(),1,1,1),":",ADDRESS(ROW()
+MATCH(2,1/(B2:$B$11=B2),1),1,1,1)),TRUE)),"General"),TEXT(MAX(INDIRECT(CONCAT(
ADDRESS(ROW(),1,1,1),":",ADDRESS(ROW()+MATCH(2,1/(B2:$B$11=B2),1),1,1,1)),TRUE))
,"General"))}. The issue is that it evaluates to #REF! when everything is written in one cell, but if I calculate MIN and MAX in separate cells and concatenate the results, everything is fine. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

In case column D is free to use (choose whichever column really if you want to) you could try:

***Input:***

[image]

***Code:***

```
Sub Test2()

Dim arr As Variant, x As Long, mx As Long, mn As Long, col As String
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B1:B" & lr).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Range("D1"), Unique:=True
    arr = .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Value
    For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        mn = .Evaluate("=MAX(IF(B2:B" & lr & "=""" & arr(x, 1) & """,A2:A" & lr & "))")
        mx = .Evaluate("=MIN(IF(B2:B" & lr & "=""" & arr(x, 1) & """,A2:A" & lr & "))")
        col = Split(.Cells(1, x).Address, "$")(1)
        Debug.Print "Column " & col & " = " & mn & "-" & mx & " " & arr(x, 1)
    Next x
    .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row).Clear
End With
End Sub
```

***Output:***

[image]

On a very large dataset, I would suggest to use a Dictionary instead maybe (array formulas are not fast). But for a rather small dataset, I guess this is a fast way.

---

Swap the line:

```
Debug.Print "Column " & col & " = " & mn & "-" & mx & " " & arr(x, 1)
```

For:

```
.Cells(x + 1, 3).Value = "Column " & col & " = " & mn & "-" & mx & " " & arr(x, 1)
```

But you might want to play around with where and how you want to output your results.

Comment: Hi JvdV thank you for this answer. It was a little bit short. the output that i get when i run this one is just removing the duplicates of column b. however as i mentioned above i also want to include the range the min and max of column a. do you have any idea how can i include that one?

Comment: thank you for this one. but i dont why im not getting that same output.. i will try to modify ur code hope i can get that same answer.

Comment: @coder, re-create the sample data, just like mine. Then move on to apply the code on your full range, to check for differences.

Comment: yes i did that one. i took a screenshot. how can i show it to you? i cant add image here in comments.

Comment: there i added the link you can see the output now. thanks

Comment: @coder, I see what you did, you probably ran the code manually using `F8`?. The values in `D` column are temporarily and are used within the rest of the code. The `Debug.Print` line puts the results in the imediate window as is now (per my example). I'll give you some code on how to put it in your sheet.

Comment: yes i tried it manually. putting a breakpoint so i can see how can i get the values because upon just pressing f5 there is a line that clearing the data for column D. thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: The whole point using column `D` was a temporary one, using it as a helper to fill an array with unique values. Go through the code, line by line to try and understand what it does :) @coder

Comment: yeah upon executing the code 1by1 i saw how it works. if you got the code on how can i put it in sheets please let me know. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

For this method to work you need to add headers in the line above data.

Put this formula in a cell:

= "Column a = " & DMIN(A1:B11;A1;B1:B2) & " - " DMAX(A1:B11;A1;B1:B2)

syntax: DMIN( "the_whole_range_of_data_including_headers";"  cell_with_header_in_column_with_search_values";" cell_with_header_and_cell_beneath_it_in_column_with_match_values")

Answer (score 0):

I created a Sub for you that might help you.
Its maybe not perfect but with a little bit of tinkering it should work for what you want to achieve.

Please accept the answer and vote for it if it helps you.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Grouping()

Dim LastRow As Integer
Dim StartRow As Integer
Dim CurrentValue As String
Dim StartValue As String

Dim i As Integer
Dim k As Integer   
Dim Outputstring As String

Dim LengthCounter As Integer

'2 -> insert Number of column B
LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

StartValue = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(1, 2).Value
StartRow = 0
LengthCounter = 0
k = 0

For i = 1 To LastRow
CurrentValue = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 2).Value

    If CurrentValue = StartValue Then
        LengthCounter = LengthCounter + 1
    Else
        Outputstring = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(StartRow, 1).Value & " - " & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i - 1, 1).Value & "  " & Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i - 1, 2).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(k, 3).Value = Outputstring
        k= k +1
        StartRow = i
        StartValue = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @G.M, upon trying your code and i put a value on StartRow = 0 and in LengthCounter = 0. i cannot see where the output is..

Comment: The output gets stored in the Variable "Outputstring" you can simply put this Value into any cell.

Comment: can you give an example on how can i put it in a cell? thanks

Comment: For example: Worksheets("Sheet 1").Cells(1, 3).Value = OutputString, you may need a counter if several outputs are required. I will just edit my answer a little.
Please up vote and accept my answer if it is helpfull to you.